# How to add line breaks (<br>) in imagestring (Text to image in PHP)

Tags: php

I am creating a business card. So, I have created the view to get user inputs such as name , email , web. When someone inputs those data to the view, all the data will show as an image. Now I get all the in one line. But, I need name , email and web in separate lines like this,

How can I Fix this ??

> Name
>
> Email
>
> Web

Here is the PHP code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$web = $_GET['web'];
$message = "<h1>$name</h1> <br> <h2>$email</h2> <br> <h3>$web</h3>";

$length = strlen($message) * 9.3;

$image = imagecreate($length,20);
$back = imagecolorallocate($image, 0,0,0);
$for = imagecolorallocate($image, 255,255,255);

imagestring($image,5,5,1,$message,$for);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($image);
}

?>
```

Here is the form.

```
<form action="" method="" class="formsize">
Your Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"> <br><br>
Your Email : <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"> <br><br>
Your Web Address : <input type="text" name="web" id="web" class="form-control"> <br><br>
<label>Upload Photo : </label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="file_img" aria-describedby="fileHelp"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"> <br><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **not line** **separate** in create image
instead u can use image_width:

```
$text = "Your Message";
$image_width = 200; // pixels
text_to_image($text, $image_width);

function text_to_image($text, $image_width, $colour = array(0,244,34), $background = array(0,0,0))
{
    $font = 5;
    $line_height = 15;
    $padding = 5;
    $text = wordwrap($text, ($image_width/10));
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    $image = imagecreate($image_width,((count($lines) * $line_height)) + ($padding * 2));
    $background = imagecolorallocate($image, $background[0], $background[1], $background[2]);
    $colour = imagecolorallocate($image,$colour[0],$colour[1],$colour[2]);
    imagefill($image, 0, 0, $background);
    $i = $padding;
    foreach($lines as $line){
        imagestring($image, $font, $padding, $i, trim($line), $colour);
        $i += $line_height;
    }
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trick to changing lines you can overwrite your text for diff positions

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$imgPath = 'images/img2.jpeg';
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgPath);
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$string = "Lat: 20.00021";
$string2 = "Long: 20.00021";
$string3 = "Data: 05/01/1995";
$fontSize = 3;
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
$x2 = 0;
$y2 = 10;
$x3 = 0;
$y3 = 20;

imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x, $y, $string, $color);
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x2, $y2, $string2, $color);
imagestring($image, $fontSize, $x3, $y3, $string3, $color);


imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).